# How to solve Null response error in Node Scheduler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-schedule

I am using the node scheduler to schedule my jobs, but getting `Null` in return, and nothing is printed when I try with try and catch the block, but still job returns `null`.

```
  const jobDate = new Date();
  const jobTz = 'Indian/Reunion';

  const job = schedule.scheduleJob({ date: jobDate, tz: jobTz }, function () {
    console.log('Job Running');
  });
```

If I do `console.log(job)` then get `null`. Not sure what the error is and why this is happening.

Comment: scheduleJob from [here](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule/blob/master/lib/schedule.js#L23) calls schedule from [here](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule/blob/master/lib/Job.js#L178). And [here](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule/blob/master/lib/Job.js#L222) an error is thrown but never reported. So weird that they do not mention in the readme to report the error. Modify the catch and console.log the error to see what it says

Comment: Also, it says in the docs that if you pass the object literal date has to be between (1-31), in your case you are passing a Date Object, not sure if that is supported.

Comment: error: 

<ref *1> Job {
  pendingInvocations: [
    Invocation {
      job: [Circular *1],
      fireDate: [CronDate],
      endDate: undefined,
      recurrenceRule: [RecurrenceRule],
      timerID: null
    }
  ],
  job: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
  callback: false,
  running: 0,
  name: '<Anonymous Job 2 2023-11-15T10:13:07.393Z>',
  ...

Comment: if you make the date field something like 15 or 16, does it return something?

Comment: same error: when passed date like - 2023-12-15T18:30:00.000Z

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for that, this issue occurs when we pass `{ date: jobDate, tz: jobTz }`.
To solve this error we can use `moment-timezone` package.

```
const startDateTime = moment.tz(jobDate, jobTz).subtract(1, "hour").toDate();

const job = schedule.scheduleJob(startDateTime, function () {
    console.log('Job Running');
});
```

If we want to use timezone then this is best way to handle. Else we can directly pass `startDateTime` in scheduler function.

In response we can get like `job.name` to get unique job Id.